# Article in "a certain writer's skills"

Tags: articles, possessives

Should there be an article in a phrase **"a certain writer's skills"**?

In phrases like this, is an article a part of a noun or a noun modifier (**"writer's"** in this case)?

Comment: What writer did you have in  mind?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"A certain writer's skills" is parsed as "{A certain writer}'s skills", and means "The skills of a certain writer".

"Certain writer's skills", with no article, is parsed as "Certain {writer's skills}", and means roughly "Certain of the skills that writers have/use/need".

Incidentally, "a certain writer's skill", singular, would be ambiguous between the two readings; some context would be needed in order to tell whether the article "a" relates to one *writer* or to one *skill*.